# Error en medias queries

Tags: css, responsive

Quiero modificar con medias queries pero los mismos no responden. La página sigue igual a pesar de que modifiqué los tamaños.

El código es el siguiente (y las medias queries lo tengo en "css/style.css">, unas de las condiciones es la que pongo en el CSS):

```css
@media screen and(max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <figure class="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" height="50px">
      </figure>
      <nav class="menu">
        <ol>
          <li>
            <a href="#portafolio" class="menu-link"> portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#skills" class="menu-link">skills</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#certificados" class="menu-link"> certificate</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#trabajemosjuntos" class="menu-link">trabajemos juntos</a>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Pero a la hora de llevar al tamaño correspondiendo no hay ningun borde. Ya reinicie el Chrome y tampoco hay cambios. No encuentro el error...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Simplemente agrega un espacio entre la palabra `and` y el primer parentesis; quedando así: `@media screen and (max-width: 480px){` y ya con eso funciona

Comment: @Aprendiz Gracias, pero no era ese el error...

Comment: yo lo probé y funciono así, sin embargo si el error era otro y ya lo identificaste entonces publicalo como respuesta para comprender entre todos cual era el fallo y de paso te lleves unos puntos

Comment: No no, no encontre el error, adjunte un screen en la publicacion. No se porque no me modifica :(

Comment: @Aprendiz ahi modifique la imagen...

Comment: @IbarraEmiliano he puesto el código como ejecutable en la pregunta y, como indica Aprendiz, al poner el espacio entre el `and` y el paréntesis, se ve correcto  el borde rojo. Debes añadir más detalles aparte de la captura, o de lo contrario la pregunta puede acabar cerrada como no se puede reproducir/fallo tipográfico.

Comment: Por lo que veo, no estás agregando el archivo al `<head>` ¿Dónde lo estás agregando el archivo `css/style.css`?